# 401 when interacting with payment gateway API

Tags: php, json, curl

I am trying to integrate my application with a payment gateway.

Their API is based on REST API and uses JSON to transport data. They have this sample code

```
$ curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-u APIKEYEXAMPLEAPIKEYEXAMPLE:APIKEYEXAMPLEAPIKEYEXAMPLE \
https://api.netbanx.com/hosted/v1/orders \
-d '{
"merchantRefNum" : "ABCDE12345",
"currencyCode" : "USD",
"totalAmount" : 1234
}'
```

And I am trying to use this to develop a php code for the same. So far my code is like this, I took in the answer provided below and modified a bit and here is my code.

```
<?php
//API Url
$url = 'https://api.netbanx.com/hosted/v1/orders';

//Initiate cURL.
$ch = curl_init($url);

//The JSON data.
$jsonData = array(
    'merchantRefNum' => '89983483',
    'currencyCode' => 'USD',
    'totalAmount' => '1234'
);

//Encode the array into JSON.
$jsonDataEncoded = json_encode($jsonData);

//Tell cURL that we want to send a POST request.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

//Attach our encoded JSON string to the POST fields.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $jsonDataEncoded);

//Set the content type to application/json
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));

//Set the header authorization 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'Authorization: Basic ZGV2Y2VudHJlNDYxNzpCLXFhMi0wLTU0OGEwM2RkLTMwMmQwMjE1MDA4M2VhZTUwYjQxYzQ0ZDIwMTE4OGM3ZmY4Yjc0ZDIxMzUwY2NiMjdiMDIxNDYwMDc4MGFlMTRkM2E2MTEzY2RmMmJkODc5MjJmZjU3MWQwMGY0ZWU=');


//Execute the request
$result = curl_exec($ch);
?>
```

My testing `API Key     devcentre4617:B-qa2-0-548a03dd-302d02150083eae50b41c44d201188c7ff8b74d21350ccb27b0214600780ae14d3a6113cdf2bd87922ff571d00f4ee`

As told in their docs, I converted the API Key to base64 added the word `Basic` gave a whitespace and got the `HTTP Authorizatoin` code as `Basic ZGV2Y2VudHJlNDYxNzpCLXFhMi0wLTU0OGEwM2RkLTMwMmQwMjE1MDA4M2VhZTUwYjQxYzQ0ZDIwMTE4OGM3ZmY4Yjc0ZDIxMzUwY2NiMjdiMDIxNDYwMDc4MGFlMTRkM2E2MTEzY2RmMmJkODc5MjJmZjU3MWQwMGY0ZWU=`

On execution I keep getting

`{"error":{"code":401,"message":"Not authorised"}}`

Is something wrong with my code? Or is the issues elsewhere?

**UPDATE!!!**

This is the working code, the issue was with the API DOCs the testing api is `https://api.test.netbanx.com/hosted/v1/orders`

```
<?php
//API Url
$url = 'https://api.test.netbanx.com/hosted/v1/orders';

//Initiate cURL.
$ch = curl_init($url);

//The JSON data.
$jsonData = array(
    'merchantRefNum' => '89983483',
    'currencyCode' => 'USD',
    'totalAmount' => '1234'
);

//Encode the array into JSON.
$jsonDataEncoded = json_encode($jsonData);

//Tell cURL that we want to send a POST request.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

//Attach our encoded JSON string to the POST fields.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $jsonDataEncoded);

//Set the content type to application/json and HTTP Authorization code

$headers = array(
    'Content-Type:application/json',
    'Authorization: Basic '. base64_encode("devcentre4617:B-qa2-0-548a03dd-302d02150083eae50b41c44d201188c7ff8b74d21350ccb27b0214600780ae14d3a6113cdf2bd87922ff571d00f4ee") //Base 64 encoding and appending Authorization: Basic 
);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

//Execute the request
$result = curl_exec($ch);
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add your username and password like this:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'APIKEYEXAMPLEAPIKEYEXAMPLE:APIKEYEXAMPLEAPIKEYEXAMPLE');
```

Good luck :)

Comment: @HansZ. could you tell me if my current code is alright or something is wrong with it?

Comment: https://developer.optimalpayments.com/en/documentation/hosted-payment-api/authentication/ here you go @Richard87 I have even tried to test it in REST EASY plugin I still keep getting the same 401 Unauthorized error

Comment: @RickRoy I think cURL takes care of Base64 encoding and decoding by itself when using basic http auth, could you try without encoding the data?

Comment: No @HansZ. I have not run the curl command I was just trying it out in the php file. I don't know how to run the curl command from windows

Comment: @Richard87 let me try it without that, do you want me to remove the Basic word too from the Authorization Key?

Comment: @RickRoy try with Basic and Any :)

Comment: @Richard87 no go, :( could you run it in terminal if you can? I don't know how to run the curl command in windows

Comment: @RickRoy did you try without encoding the username and password with base64

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68177/discussion-between-rick-roy-and-richard87).